# Facebook Comments for individual URLs

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I'm trying to add Facebook Comments across my website. The XFBML code given by Facebook requires a specific a specific href value:

```
<fb:comments href="http://www.url.com" num_posts="3" width="800"></fb:comments>
```

How can I grab the URL of the page and add it to the  without it triggering the "Warning: http://invalid.invalid/ is unreachable."

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in your .aspx page:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
<fb:comments href="<%=Request.Url.ToString()%>" num_posts="3" width="800"></fb:comments>
```